# populate a combobox from a dictionary <string, class>

Tags: dictionary, combobox, populate

I want to populate a combobox from a dictionary  but I receive an `error of argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'class'`. The class is Barcodereader. How I should do it? any other option? 
This is the code I want to use but doesn´t work:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, BarcodeReader> CodeType =
           new Dictionary<string, BarcodeReader> 
                    {
                        {"Codabar", BarcodeReader.CODABAR},
                        {"Code 39", BarcodeReader.CODE39},
                    };
        // Populate cbobox
        cboCodeType.Items.AddRange(CodeType.Keys.ToArray());
        cboCodeType.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `BarcodeReader.CODABAR` and `BarcodeReader.CODE39` are int values, not instances of BarcodeReader. Try changing the CodeType Dictionary's Value type to int as follows:

```cs
private static IDictionary<string, int> CodeType =
    new Dictionary<string, int> 
    {
        {"Codabar", BarcodeReader.CODABAR},
        {"Code 39", BarcodeReader.CODE39},
    };
```

It seems to me the library does not provide any way to retrieve BarcodeReader instances, the public read methods all accept barcodeType as int.